# Setting environmental variables with !Ref in AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I'm using SAM CLI v0.8.1. I'm trying to set environmental variable MY_TABLE_VAR as name of the table in my resources (MyTableResource). However, while running my app locally, the MY_TABLE_VAR is undefined. Can you tell me what's wrong in my template and how can I set it properly? Following is my SAM template:

```
Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 30
        Runtime: nodejs8.10        
        Environment:
            Variables:
                MY_TABLE_VAR: !Ref MyTableResource
Resources:
    MyTableResource:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
        Properties:
          TableName: table1
          PrimaryKey:
            Name: id
            Type: String
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my understanding, the `Globals` section cannot reference resources in the `Resources` section (the dependency is in the other direction, since whatever is added to the `Globals` section is added [to all Serverless Functions and APIs](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#globals-section) in the `Resources`section). To work around this, I suggest that you use either [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) or [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), e.g.

```
Parameters:
    TableName:
        Type: String
        Default: table1

Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 30
        Runtime: nodejs8.10        
        Environment:
            Variables:
                MY_TABLE_VAR: !Ref TableName

Resources:
    MyTableResource:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
        Properties:
          TableName: !Ref TableName
          # more table config....
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the `Globals` CAN reference resources in the `Resources` section, but (probably) not all types. I managed to declare a `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion` resource object and set the `Layers` property in the `Globals: Function` scope, despite the layer being created inside the `Resources` section.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I just found this question with a Google search. I wanted to use the name of a function as a parameter to all other functions in my template. If you override the environment variable on the source function, the circular dependency goes away:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        LOG_LEVEL: WARNING
        SPECIAL_FUNCTION: !GetAtt SpecialFunction.Arn

Resources:
  SpecialFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/special_function
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SPECIAL_FUNCTION: Overriding global value to avoid circular dependency
      Handler: special_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
  OtherFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/other_function
      Handler: other_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
```

`OtherFunction` will have the ARN of `SpecialFunction` in the `SPECIAL_FUNCTION` environment variable.